# Efficiently break an array every X number of values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript

I want to split an array into a group of values starting at the end and leaving the beginning as a remander array. Here's an example of the goal:

```
arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
interval = 5
#chop
output = [[0,1],[2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11]]
```

What's that most efficient way of doing this?

Thanks for any help?

Comment: Look into "Array.slice"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split array into chunks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
    interval = 5,
    output = [];

while (arr.length >= interval) {
    output.unshift(arr.splice(-interval, interval));
}
output.unshift(arr);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: +1, although modifying the original array is unnecessary work (and for all we know, not desirable for other reasons). Note, though, that inferring the second argument like that is a SpiderMonkey extension (not standard), for compatibility you'd need `splice(-interval, interval)`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Added the length part of `.splice()` as mentioned. And for the original array. You're right, but maybe it isn't needed anymore after breaking it up so maybe this could work out.

Comment: I did need to keep the original but I ended up creating a clone and splicing in a similar way. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

Can't speak for CoffeeScript, but in JavaScript I don't think there's anything that does that specifically, you'll just need a loop of [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) calls. Either loop backward using a negative index (which means "from the end"), or just take the first `src.length % interval` items on the first pass.

Comment: Ok, will probably use slice. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Reverse. Slice. Push. Reverse.